# How to trigger a Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline job from a GitHub pull request

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

It looks like the GitHubPullRequestBuilder is not compatible with Jenkins v2.0 pipeline jobs.

How do you configure a pipeline job to be triggered from a GitHub pull request event?
The documentation on this topic is sparse and I cannot find any examples of this.  Or is it better to create a web-hook in GitHub to trigger the pipeline job on the PR event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to use Pipeline with GitHub pull requests is to put the script into your repository under the name `Jenkinsfile` and then install the *GitHub Branch Source* plugin. [Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline-as-code/)

Comment: will that work only for PRs of members of the organization, or also for PRs from external contributors?

Comment: @elopio, the plugin has options to enable/disable building of PRs from the same repository as well as from external repositories. It's not exactly what you're asking for, but probably close enough.

Comment: There is this official [jenkinsci/workflow-demo](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/workflow-demo/) docker image for playing around with PRs tests and `Jenkinsfile`. I was wondering if it was possible to have those nice red and green checks on the PRs and it's totally possible ([example here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/57)) :) And here's a [useful post about multibranch workflows](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/)

Comment: while this does allow you build PR branches, as far as I can tell there's no way to get the info about the PR that the old plugin used to offer:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin#GitHubpullrequestbuilderplugin-EnvironmentVariables

Comment: @grahamrhay some comparable information is available, such as the `CHANGE_TITLE` environment variable for example. See `env` documentation for available variables.

Answer (score 47):

I had similar issue. Here’s what worked for me

Pre-req

- Jenkins ver. 2+  (I was using Jenkins 2.60)
- Github (or Githhub
  enterprise) account
- Your github and Jenkins must be able to talk to
  each other.

On Github

1. create a github Personal Access Token (PAT) with relevant rights.
2. For your repo, create a webhook with

   - URL as `YourJenkinsURL/github-webhook/`
   - Choose ‘Let me select individual events’ and check ‘Pull Request’
3. Add a *Jenkinsfile* to the root folder of your repo. For testing purpose you could put content as a basic hello world like below

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello World ...'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On Jenkins

1. Install **GitHub Pull Request Builder** plugin. (You also need “Github” plugin but that should normally be installed as part of Jenkins ver 2+)
2. Jenkins – Credentials

   - Add github Personal Access Token (PAT) as a ‘secret text’ credential.
   - Add github username-password as ‘username-password’ credential.
3. Manage Jenkins – Configure System

   - Github – Github Servers : This is part of the Github plugin. Add a github server.  ‘API URL’ It will default to https://api.github.com. If you are using enterprise github, replace with enterprise github url followed by /api/v3. For credential select the PAT option. Test the connection. ‘Manage Hooks’ is checked.
   - GitHub Pull Request Builder : for ‘GitHub Server API URL’ use same url as specified in Github Server section. Leave ‘Shared Secret’ blank. For credentials use ‘username-password’ credential. Test credentials to ensure its working. In my settings, ‘Auto-manage webhooks’ was checked.
4. Pipeline Job

   - Create a new item using ‘Pipeline’ option. Note: This is the vanilla Pipeline job, not Multibranch Pipeline.
   - General Section: Check ‘Github Project’ – Project URL : Enter your github repo url
   - Build Triggers: Check ‘GitHub Pull Request Builder’

     - For ‘GitHub API credentials’ select option you set for GitHub pull request builder in ‘Manage Jenkins – Configure System’ screen
     - For admin list: add your username
     - Check Use github hooks for build triggering
   - Pipeline:

     1. Select ‘Pipeline Script from SCM’. Note this assumes that the root folder of your repo will contain a ‘Jenkinsfile’
     2. SCM: Select ‘Git’
     3. Repositories – enter repo detail. For credentials use ‘username-password’ based credentials.
     4. Click Advanced and add refspec as `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
     5. Branch – should be `${sha1}`
     6. Script Path: defaulted to *Jenkinsfile*, leave as is.
     7. Lightweight Checkout - Uncheck this (https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/507)

That’s it. You are all set. Creating a PR on master branch of your repo should now trigger your Jenkins Pipeline job

Some observations

- Redelivering the webhook payload of a PR from github does not trigger the pipeline but opening a new PR or even re-opening a closed PR on github, triggers the pipeline job
- In Pipeline Job Configuration, if you choose “Pipeline Script” and paste your pipeline script in there, the job doesn't trigger !!!

Comment: Can't we do the same with multibranch pipeline? Because the branch I want play with is not the master branch. @Deepak Rao

Comment: `Build Triggers: Check ‘GitHub Pull Request Builder’` that option isn't there for me.  The plugin is installed because that option is present on other projects which are not using a jenkinsfile.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and well documented answer. This saves the day, this should have been the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

The flow in a nutshell can go like this:

1. You create your pipeline as code and save it in a file called `Jenkinsfile` at the root dir of your project. That code should describe how your project will get built. See here for examples: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/
2. Then you should create a new "Multibranch Pipeline Project" item in your Jenkins. You should set this up so as to scan your repo of step 1.
3. Now whenever you get a new PR branch opened on your step 1 repo, the branch will be checked-out and will get built according to the Jenkinsfile instructions included with it. You can set up more conditions on what gets built and when if you want to.

*Notes:*

1. "Multibranch Pipeline Project" example documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline-as-code/ (scroll down to Multibranch Pipeline Projects)
2. Keep in mind that getting the plugin to build a PR after commending on the PR does not work. There is a discussion analyzing this here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/298 There are workarounds (also described in that discussion) but they are quite messy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Below Steps for Triggering Jenkins Job Automatically on Pull request generated on GitHub

1. Create a web hook on GitHub i.e. http:///generic- 
   webhook-trigger/invoke
2. Content Type :application/json
3. Select Pull Request as event Now github Configuration Part is done.

**Jenkins Job Configuration**

5. Download Generic Webhook Trigger in Jenkins
6. Git Hub Configuration On Jenkins

[Git Hub Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4HLo.jpg)

7.Select Generic Webhook Trigger on jenkins
8.[Generic Webhook Trigger Configuration on Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpcHk.jpg)and follow step 9

9.After doing step 7 Jenkins job will get trigger on PullRequest
10.Step 8 required to get  information from Pull request Payload
11.[Branch configuration inside Generic Webhook Trigger to get Branch details from Pull Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf12h.png)

Thanks