# How to integrate Jenkins with Github to trigger pipeline on pull request

Tags: github, jenkins, integration

I used the GitHub builder plugin, which has become obsolete now. You can find it here: [link to the obsolete plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/).

I've now discovered an alternative solution, which can be found here: [link to the alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850485/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-job-from-a-github-pull-request).

After configuring it, GitHub is capable of sending webhooks to Jenkins, and the following logs are visible in Jenkins system logs:

```
INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbPullRequest 
Created Pull Request #326 on the repository by an unidentified user () updated at: 10/8/23, 7:18 PM SHA: 894c1cb590b67a2f87d1e754cb8dbe24920153c8
INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbPullRequest updatePR
Pull request #326 was updated/initialized on the repository at 10/8/23, 7:45 PM by null (PR update)
```

However, despite these configurations and logs, the pipeline in the project is not being triggered. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

trying to automatically trigger the Jenkins pipeline on PR creation in github repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins and list all the branches Jenkins is listening to. You can only list branches that have Jenkinfile on branch root. Once successfully done, the pipeline will run everytime a branch gets a commit. This tutorial had helped me a lot:

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/github-branch-source-multibranch-pipeline-cloudbees-ci